# SQL Statement not terminating when executed from trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have made a little solution to export a customers data row to a csv file, when a specific column ist updated.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER dbo.EXPORT_CUSTOMER_TYPE 
   ON  dbo.ADDRESSES 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (UPDATE(SYMBOL0))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ADR_ID INT = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM inserted)
        
        -- TEMPORARY TABLE TO STORE THE COLUMNS WHICH SHOULD BE EXPORTED
        declare @ExportCols TABLE (
            idx int identity(1, 1),
            colName nvarchar(255)
        )

        -- READ INI FILE TO GET THE COMMA SEPARATED COLUMN NAMES
        declare @cols_dirtyString nvarchar(50);
        declare @outputfile nvarchar(255);
        exec dbo.lsp_ReadIniFile
            'C:\temp\SQL_READ_FILE_TEST\config.ini', 'ExportConfig', 'ExportColumns', @cols_dirtyString OUTPUT

        exec dbo.lsp_ReadIniFile
            'C:\temp\SQL_READ_FILE_TEST\config.ini', 'ExportConfig', 'OutputFile', @outputfile OUTPUT

        set @outputfile = REPLACE(REPLACE(@outputfile, '{date}', CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23)), '{id}', CAST(@ADR_ID AS NVARCHAR))

        -- FILL THE TEMPORARY TABLE WITH COLUMN NAMES AND TEMPORARY IDS 
        INSERT INTO @ExportCols
        SELECT * FROM string_split(@cols_dirtyString, ',')

        -- LOOP THROUGH THE TEMP TABLE AND BUILD THE QUERY STRING
        declare @index int = 1;
        declare @rowcount int = (select count(*) from @ExportCols);
        declare @statement nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT '

        while (@index <= @rowcount)
        begin
            declare @colName nvarchar(255) = (select colName from @ExportCols where idx = @index)
            set @statement = @statement + @colName + ', '
            set @index = @index + 1;
        end

        set @statement = substring(@statement, 0, len(@statement))
        set @statement = @statement + ' FROM CobraDemoData.dbo.ADDRESSES WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@ADR_ID AS NVARCHAR)

        -- EXECUTE THE BUILT QUERY STRING
        DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max) = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "' + @statement + '" queryout "' + @outputfile + '" -T -c -t ";" -S T470p-DH\DEV'''
        EXEC(@ExportSQL)


    END
END
GO
```

Couple things to note.
I do know that this isn't a very good approach on solving this requirement. It is a customers WISH to do it this way. I have no choice. I also know that currently the script only works if the inserted table has a single row. This is an early state and will get sorted out. :)

If I execute the logic inside the trigger on itself the file gets exported with the necessary data, as I want it to be.
But as soon as I put it in the trigger and update a row, the statement never finishes. The file is created, but permanently "in use".
I don't usually work with tsql, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a huge [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). A `TRIGGER` should have a *minimal* impact on the DML statement. This Trigger not only has a `WHILE`, but also uses dynamic statements, and `xp_cmdshell`. It also is flawed if more than 1 row in is the DML statement, as it'll process **one** arbitrary row in the `inserted` table and that's it. You also don't declare the length of your `varchar` in some cases. None of this logic should be in a `TRIGGER`, and any logic that *is* in a `TRIGGER` should be parsing the **entirety** of `inserted`, not one arbitrary row.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, I totally agree. But I have no choice. To clarify this, I have updated the post.

Comment: You always have a choice. All the trigger should be doing is inserting the relevant data into a pooling table. Then an automated process should be running at regular intervals to do the "grunt work".

Comment: @Larnu Again, I agree. But still, this is exactly the way I MUST do it. No regular intervals or alike.

Comment: As the developer, @arvenyon , it is your responsibility to ensure that you don't implement such flawed process as this. Despite the saying, the customer isn't always right, and as developers we need to tell them when they are wrong. *We* (as developers) are technically trained, not them (the customers). For the same reason I will happily tell my manager when they are "wrong" when they ask me to do something a specific way in SQL, because the idea is flawed, but I will instead show them the correct way. That is exactly what you need to do here.

Comment: You are going to find it very unlikely that anyone here is going to help you create a inherently flawed answer, because that answer will not be helpful, and will very likely attract downvotes from the experienced members of the community; who know that the answer is flawed and thus not helpful.

Comment: What you are trying to do won't be possible inside a trigger. The trigger code is still running inside the context of the user's transaction and the data hasn't actually been committed yet. You're asking BCP to export the contents of the table, which it will be doing from a different database connection, and so BCP will be blocked infinitely by the locks your transaction is still holding on the dbo.ADDRESSES table and index(es).

Comment: Oh so it is technically not possible... now that you explain it that way, I actually have something I can argue with. Perfect. I thank you kind sir. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, that isn't actually true, unfortunately for the OP's case. Within a `TRIGGER` when referencing the table, the updated rows **are** inside it when using an `AFTER` trigger.

Comment: For evidence, see this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f3d38f400a68167e0f44ac15083fbf8). This is also why triggers that `JOIN` the `inserted` virtual table back to the triggering table work on triggers like `AFTER INSERT`.

Comment: Aside: If you know that the trigger will only work correctly for a single updated row then you ought to check for that and handle it, e.g. `if ( select Count(*) from Inserted ) > 1 Throw 50000, 'Foo_Update_Trigger cannot handle more than one updated row.', 42;`.